# When building a SelectQuery, why can't I use the alias from addExpression() in a condition()?

Tags: database

I'm trying to search for nodes with field values that satisfy a mathematical formula. I can build a SelectQuery that will find all nodes and return the value of the computation for each result using addExpression(), but I cannot seem to accomplish the final step of only returning the correct nodes using condition().

Here is a simplified example:

```
$myquery = db_select('node', 'n');

// Use innerJoin() since node field values are stored in separate tables
$myquery->innerJoin('field_data_field_number_one', 'one', 'n.nid = one.entity_id');
$myquery->innerJoin('field_data_field_number_two', 'two', 'n.nid = two.entity_id');

// Add basic node fields and the two value fields so they will be available in the results
$myquery->fields('n');
$myquery->addField('one', 'field_number_one_value', 'one');
$myquery->addField('two', 'field_number_two_value', 'two');

// Add the computation using addExpression()
// In this example the computation has been reduced to a simple sum
$myquery->addExpression('(one.field_number_one_value + two.field_number_two_value)', 'sumcalc');

// Only return nodes of type desired_type
$myquery->condition('n.type', 'desired_type');

// The query will execute properly without the following line
$myquery->condition('sumcalc', 5, '<');

$prex = $myquery->preExecute();

if ($prex) {
  $qresult = $myquery->execute();
  foreach ($qresult as $qrecord) {
    // Without the erroneous condition above, this line will print each result
    // and each result will contain the value of the calculation added via addExpression()
    dpm($qrecord);
  }
}
```

If I try to execute the code above, I get the following error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sumcalc' in 'where clause'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL you're trying to build is invalid - you can't refer to an expression field in a `WHERE` clause.

You need a `HAVING` clause for that, which in Drupal-ese is:

```
$myquery->havingCondition('sumcalc', 5, '<');
```